# Getting contacts location from graph api in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an android application in which I am using facebook open graph api to get the friends list. Its easy to get the friend's list, but what if I want the location of my friend through graph api? Is this possible? If so, then what steps should be taken for a graph api call?

```
try {
            return Factory.getFacebook().request(url[urlCount]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Where url is "me/friends".